# Get a Jar file's manifest by knowing it's location

Tags: java, maven, jar, manifest

By knowing the jar's name and location, is there a way of grabbing it's manifest and getting it's attributes?

I have the following code:

```
public static String readRevision() throws IOException {

    URL jarLocationUrl = MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
    String jarLocation = new File(jarLocationUrl.toString()).getParent();
    String jarFilename = new File(jarLocationUrl.toString()).getAbsoluteFile().getName();

   // This below is what I want to get from the manifest
    String revision = manifest.getAttributes("Revision-Number").toString();

    return revision;
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html#JarFile-java.io.File-, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html#getManifest--

Answer (score 2):

Most *standard* attributes can be read directly from the [Package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html) class:

```
String version = MyApplication.class.getPackage().getSpecificationVersion();
```

To read custom atttributes, don’t use the java.io.File class.  You should never assume a URL is a `file:` URL.

Instead, you can use a [JarInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarInputStream.html):

```
Manifest manifest;
try (JarInputStream jar = new JarInputStream(ljarLocationUrl.openStream())) {
    manifest = jar.getManifest();
}

Attribute.Name name = new Attribute.Name("Revision-Number");
String revisionNumber = (String) manifest.getMainAttributes().get(name);
```

Alternatively, you could read the manifest directly by constructing a [JarURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html) compound URL:

```
URL manifestURL = new URL("jar:" + jarLocationUrl + "!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");

Manifest manifest;
try (InputStream manifestSource = manifestURL.openStream()) {
    manifest = new Manifest(manifestSource);
}

Attribute.Name name = new Attribute.Name("Revision-Number");
String revisionNumber = (String) manifest.getMainAttributes().get(name);
```

Note that [ProtectionDomain.getCodeSource() can return null](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/ProtectionDomain.html#getCodeSource--).  A better way to specify a version number in an application is to put it in either the Specification-Version or Implementation-Version attribute of the manifest, so it can be read from a Package method.  Remember that while Implementation-Version is a free-form string, [a Specification-Version value must consist of groups of ASCII digits separated by periods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html#getSpecificationVersion--).

Another way is simply to create a data file and include it in your .jar, which you can then read using [Class.getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) or [Class.getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-):

```
Properties props = new Properties();
try (InputStream stream = MyApplication.class.getResourceAsStream("application.properties")) {
    props.load(stream);
}

String revisionNumber = props.getProperty("version");
```